# Propertygrid in netcoreapp

Tags: propertygrid, netcoreapp3.1

I used to be able to do this in Net472, but run into an error when I tried to do the same in Netcoreapp3.1

```
enter code here
        BrowsableAttribute theDescriptorBrowsableAttribute = (BrowsableAttribute)theDescriptor.Attributes[typeof(BrowsableAttribute)];
        FieldInfo browsablility = theDescriptorBrowsableAttribute.GetType().GetField("Browsable", BindingFlags.IgnoreCase | BindingFlags.NonPublic | BindingFlags.Instance);

        // Set the Descriptor's "Browsable" Attribute
        browsablility.SetValue(theDescriptorBrowsableAttribute, isBrowsable);
```

browsablility returns null. it seems it is now a OnInitOnly and cannot be set.

Any idea?  I just want to make the item visible or invisible based on attributes.

Comment: You code relies on a private field named "browsable" that's probably gone. Why don't you just use `BrowsableAttribute.Browsable` public property?

Comment: Browsable is Read only and cannot be changed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally resolve the problem by creating a custom attribute and set that attribute to true or false.  and assign that custom attribute to propertgird.BrowsableAttribute